# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on executor of spark job

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to write to dynamodb via spark job for each record in a hive table. the detailed error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 12 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 12.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 775, ip-10-0-0-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
```

The code snippet is as follows:

```
object ObjName {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      print(classOf[com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder].getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath())

      val session = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("app_name")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate()
      import session.implicits._
      session.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

      session.sql("""
            select
                email,
                name
            from db.tbl
            """).rdd.repartition(40)
        .foreachPartition( iter => {
          val random = new Random();
          val client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard.withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("access key", "secret key"))).build()
          val dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client)
          val table = dynamoDB.getTable("table_name")
          iter.foreach(row => {
            val item = new Item().withPrimaryKey("email", row.getString(0)).withNumber("ts", (System.currentTimeMillis)*1000+random.nextInt(999+1)).withString("name", row.getString(1))
            table.putItem(item)
          })
        })
      }
}
```

maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.170</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.170</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.170</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmespath-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.170</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

At the beginning of the main method, I printed the jar file location of class `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder` which is successful, so it means this class is loaded well on driver node.

Also, I execute `jar tvf package.jar  | grep -i AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder --color` and it's confirmed that this class is in my packaged jar file.

The command to submit the spark job is as follows. No matter adding the `--jars` or not will both complain the same error as shown above. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
spark-submit --class MainClassName --jars /mnt/home/hadoop/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.170.jar,/mnt/home/hadoop/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.170.jar,/mnt/home/hadoop/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.170.jar,/mnt/home/hadoop/jmespath-java-1.11.170.jar --driver-memory 3G --num-executors 20 --executor-memory 4G --executor-cores 4 package.jar
```

Comment: Sorry, but how is this java?

Comment: rectified. @Rigidity

Comment: :P I've just been looking around for Java questions to answer xD

Comment: Could that be that you have different versions of dynamodb installed on your cluster nodes which conflict with what you're providing?